# How to use two conditions in R?

Tags: r

so I made an example in SQL below:

```
SELECT A_NAME,
NVL(ROUND(AVG(CASE
WHEN M_TYPE_NAME = 'OldMarket' THEN A_PRICE END)), 0) AS OldMarket,
NVL(ROUND(AVG(CASE
WHEN M_TYPE_NAME = 'NewMarket' THEN A_PRICE END)), 0) AS NewMarket
FROM PRICE
GROUP BY A_NAME;
```

I'm trying to change this into R using

```
install.packages("googleVis")
library(googleVis)
```

how can I put two conditions into one?(Is it possible in R?)

Comment: Please review [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: googleVis is a visualization package. Why are you looking there for an SQL interface?  Take a look at the `sqldf` package.